# How to adjust when i am 5'5 foot tall and having a 42 cm roadbike frame?

Tags: road-bike, frames, stem, framebuilding

Im planning to buy a roadbike frameset in my local store but they say that the size of the frame is 42cm and i am 5'5 should i buy that frame?

Comment: Generally, the bike store will fit you to the frame. What do you mean that the size of the frame is 42cm - do they only have that size in stock? I agree with Adam, that is likely to be too small for you, but the store should recommend a frame of the correct size. That is the reason we have bike stores. If they don't do that, then you probably don't want to patronize that store.

Comment: Don't buy a bike unseen.  You have to get your leg over one and test ride.

Comment: Almost guaranteed not to fit.

Comment: Do you have a geometry chart? How size is measured differs from manufacturer to manufacturer.

Comment: Obligatory [Jens Voigt on a child's bike in the Tour de France](https://cycling-passion.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Jens-Voigt-borrowed-child-size-bike-Tour-de-France-2010-stage-16.jpg)

Comment: Find a competent bikeshop. This one's certainly not.

Answer (score 3):

That sounds like an extremely small frame for you. In fact, it sounds like an extremely small frame, period—frames usually aren't sized that small.

Every manufacturer is going to have its own sizing guidelines, but in rough terms, I would expect someone of your height to ride a 52-cm frame.

Comment: I'd actually think around a 48-49cm frame, but we're not far apart. I'd guess the height recommendations for something like a 42cm frame are for around 5'.

Comment: I suspect the 42cm is the actual seat tube length on a sloping top tube bike, rather than the conventional "size" based on a theoretical seat tube on a horizontal top tube bike. Could easily be the equivalent of a 48 or 50 and be appropriately sized for the OP. We need to know more about the actual frame geometry

Comment: @Andrew That's a good point. AFAICT most manufacturers these days display the notional size on the frame, but this might be an outlier.